# How to deploy contract over 25kb?

Tags: compiler-errors, token, solidity

How is it possible that contract over size limitation is deployed on main net?

https://bscscan.com/address/0xb8a5e028f833f08a29564ded368b4cacb4e18ff5#code

Answer (score 0):

The linked contract bytecode has a length of 37,684 hex characters, which is 18,842 bytes.

Which is below the limit of 24,576 bytes (hex value 0x6000) specified in the [EIP-170](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md).

Answer (score 0):

Use import.
e.g. `import ./anotherSolidityCode.sol` OR `import "https://github.com/some/codes.sol"` etc.